# How to link css to ejs templates in node

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a beginner node js server. I am able to render dynamic html using ejs templates but i cannot link css styling to them

I have set up a public directory to store the assets like images and external css files. i have linked to the static contents to express using

```
app.use(express.static('/public', __dirname + '/public'));
```

my public folder has images(.jpg) which are rendered but the css in the public folder cannot be rendered.

```
file structure : 
node_modules
models
views
public > app.css, hero.jpg
server.js
package.json
```

the express app is as below :  server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ejs = require('ejs');
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public');
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set('views',__dirname+'/views');
app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
   res.render('home',{
        title: "HomePage",
        date : new Date().getFullTYear()
        }
app.listen(3000);
```

---

the home.ejs file has a head section as :

```
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title> My Website <%= title %> </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css" type="text/stylesheet">
</head>
```

I expected the app.css to load like the  in the home.ejs file. But its not working

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I could guess you are setting the static file folder to be /public.

Try modifing you css link to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/app.css" type="text/stylesheet">`

or try setting the static file config like this:

`app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))`

and then `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/app.css" type="text/stylesheet">`

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your public folder this way

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

That means you can serve these files as if these were in the root folder. So you can link your css and images this way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css" type="text/stylesheet">


// in case of image
<img src="/hero.jpg">
```

When you declare public folder like this

```
app.use(express.static('/public', __dirname + '/public'));
```

you set a **virtual path prefix** for your files and in that case you have to add `public` in the url path of each file, like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/app.css" type="text/stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

To use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve as a part of public folder:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Create public folder under the root folder. Under that folder create `css` folder if you want. So, structure will be link `public/css/style.css`

You can access `style.css` like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```